Using trim_messages and RunnableWithMessageHistory in LangChain together
from operator import itemgetter

from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough

chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(messages=itemgetter("messages") | trimmer)
    | prompt
    | model
)

response = chain.invoke(
    {
        "messages": messages + [HumanMessage(content="what's my name?")],
        "language": "English",
    }
)

The above code is from the LangChain documentation for creating a chatbot with memory. They use trim_messages to reduce the messages to fit the context window which is understandable.
But, then they wrap this chain with RunnableWithMessageHistory which doesn't make sense to me using:
with_message_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="messages",
)

config = {"configurable": {"session_id": "abc20"}}

response = with_message_history.invoke(
    {
        "messages": messages + [HumanMessage(content="whats my name?")],
        "language": "English",
    },
    config=config,
)

response.content

Considering the fact that RunnableWithMessageHistory is supposed to automatically log and fetch messages previously sent, why do they have previoud messages being added in the messages key in the dictionary being passed to invoke method? I am very very confused as to what's going on over here. Please explain to me how the bottom code works. If it is wrong, how can I integrate trim_messages to automatically fetch messages from history.
I am just confused. I don't even know what to try.
